# Multiline title sided by epigraph

Tags: chapters

I want to customize one of my chapter titles to emphasize its acronym. I believe that splitting it onto multiple lines it a good solution, but I would also like to make the first letters stand out. Also, I note there is a lot of white space on the right, but I figured I should be able to move the epigraph there. How could I achieve this?

What I have:
[image: current version]

What I want:
[image: desired version]

Ideally, there would be a better way to emphasize the SLAM letters than colour. I was thinking of multi-line letters, similar to this, but I don't know where I can get those from:

[image]

I am open to other suggestions :)

Thank you!

---

My MWE is quite involved and doesn't look exactly like what I have (the epigraph with is smaller, but it doesn't matter).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lmodern}        % use modern latin fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8 bit output font encoding with more glyphs
\usepackage{xcolor}         % more color choices
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes} % for correct use of `` '' ... meh!
\usepackage{blindtext}

% an epigraph is a small 'inspirational' text displayed at the beggining of a chapter
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.8\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushleft}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% provided by school in a .sty file
\topmargin -45truept     %    Nominal distance from top of paper to top of page
\textwidth=159truemm
\oddsidemargin=0truemm \evensidemargin=0truemm
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{slides}
  {\textheight 240truemm}
  {
        \ifcase \@ptsize
            % mods for 10 pt (\baselineskip=12pt)
            \textheight 682pt  % Height of text (including footnotes and figures)
        \or % mods for 11 pt (\baselineskip=13.6pt)
            \textheight 690 pt    % Height of text (including footnotes and figures)
        \or % mods for 12 pt  (\baselineskip=15pt)
            \textheight 685 pt    % Height of text (including footnotes and figures)
        \fi
  }
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

%% =============================================================================
% This should be in .cls file, ideally
% Remove "Chapter x" line before a new chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{35 pt}% Space before the chapter name
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
\bfseries\Huge
#1% The chapter's name
\par\nobreak\vspace{35 pt}}} % Space after chapter name
\makeatother

%% =============================================================================

\begin{document}

\chapter[Simultaneous Localisation And Mapping]{Simultaneous\\Localisation\\And\\Mapping}

% no idea why in my real report this is wider ...
\epigraph{`` Using sensory information to locate the robot in its environment is the most fundamental problem to provide a mobile robot with autonomous capabilities. ''}{Ingemar J Cox, 1990}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm not in a position to experiment, but one way of making the initial letters stand out more (at the cost of having a ragged left margin) might be to align the initial letters to the right with the second letters aligned to the left, so that each line is still a distinct word.  (the M might be too wide for this to look good, but it shouldn't take too long to try it out.)

Comment: If XeTeX/LuaTeX is an option, you could, of course, take your pick of available opentype/truetype fonts. For traditional engines, take a look [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html), for example.

Comment: Note that it is somewhat out of date, though. You don't need to do all the `\input` stuff to use the decorative initials any more, for example. There is a package available for each of the 27 options. (If I remember the number correctly.) The CTAN page doesn't tell you this, either, which isn't very helpful :(.

Comment: There is also [this font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/bbold/). However, if you use it, make sure to install the type1 version and ensure it is correctly used. The type1 version is not included in TeX Live - only the bitmap.

Comment: @cfr thanks for your suggestions. It is a bit late to switch my LaTeX engine now, but I will try it after submitting my thesis :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\epigraphhead` can be used to place the epigraph appropriately. The exact distance adjustment depends on the content of the chapter title and epigraph. See the documentation for details. Obviously, this also requires adjusting the alignment and width of the epigraph appropriately.

For the first letters, I experimented with one of the decorative fonts supported by the `emerald` package. See the documentation for installation instructions as this is not included in TeX Live.

I've also switched to `geometry` as this is generally better than setting layout dimensions manually. Note that it matters that you set the epigraph width after changing `\textwidth` if it is specified relative to that dimension.

Finally, I note that you are not, in fact, using British English quotation marks but American English. I don't know whether this matters to you or not, but it seemed odd.

I would, in any case, not recommend using quotation marks around an epigraph. It is like putting them around a block quotation, although not, perhaps, as definitely incorrect as I'm not sure what punctuation rules exist for epigraphs. It looks odd to me, let's say.

In any case, here is the result

[image: fancy chapter heading]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{epigraph,etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushleft}
% \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
\usepackage[textwidth=159mm, hmargin ratio=1:1, vmargin ratio=3:2, verbose]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \normalfont
  \ifcase \@ptsize
    \geometry{textheight=240mm}%
    \or
    \geometry{textheight=243mm}%
    \or
    \geometry{textheight=241mm}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.4\textwidth}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{35 pt}% Space before the chapter name
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
    \bfseries\Huge
    #1
    \par\nobreak\vspace{35 pt}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\fcap[1]{{\myfancyfont #1}}
\usepackage{emerald}
\let\myfancyfont\ECFDecadenceWithoutTheDiamonds

\begin{document}

\chapter[Simultaneous Localisation And Mapping]{\fcap Simultaneous\\\fcap Localisation\\\fcap And\\\fcap Mapping}
\epigraphhead[150]{\epigraph{\raggedleft `` Using sensory information to locate the robot in its environment is the most fundamental problem to provide a mobile robot with autonomous capabilities. ''}{Ingemar J Cox, 1990}}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for such a thorough answer ! I will look into the other problems as well. _british quotes_ matter but I thought just using the package would adapt *` ` ... ' '*  accordingly. Thanks for the heads up! Indeed, `geometry` is better than my school's 1986 `.sty`!

Comment: I got an error: File `emerald.sty' not found. \let . thanks in advance

Comment: @MamounMohammed Please read the second paragraph above.